# Nginx sub-path shows 404 error

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup nginx to work with a subpath but I am receiving 404 error.I am using default location and html file.

Nginx config is the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen[::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  server_name localhost;

  ## serving gogs
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

  ## serving laravel-based web app
  location /yt/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

The firewall (ufw) is disabled and all ports are open via mikrotik.Everything is fine when open the / path but when I go to /yt/ I get a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if configuration is correct, when i compared with my local simple setup i found it little different . Please try this one if it works.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen[::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  server_name localhost;

  ## serving gogs
  location /yt/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem was that I hadnt created a subfolder inside html folder in nginx.Just viewed the error logs and found it. Thanks a lot.